# Hibernate Enver doesn't audit the field which is using in the soft delete?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using hibernate.envers settings:

```
properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", "_HISTORY");
properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", "true");
```

The main table like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE person SET deleted = NOW() WHERE id = ?", check = ResultCheckStyle.COUNT)
@Where(clause = "deleted is NULL")
@Audited
public class Person {
  @Id
  private UUID id;

  private OffsetDateTime deleted;

  //omit other fields
}
```

When delete event happens, the Person_HISTORY table will store all fields of Person except `deleted` field. (`deleted` field in `Person_HISTORY` table was null)

Any idea how to store `deleted` field into Person_HISTORY when deleting event happen?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, the modification to `deleted` is not included in the `PostDeleteEvent`.

Hibernate builds the state that is included in the `PostDeleteEvent` once, at the beginning of the entity deletion workflow.  For traditional use, this makes sense because the statement being executed is a `DELETE`, so the row is not being modified.

The conundrum here is a `@SQLDelete` merely replaces the generated `DELETE` statement the entity's persister uses with a custom version.  Generally speaking, the SQL you provide could be anything as long as it is syntactically valid DML.

What Hibernate does not know is that the replacement SQL in this case is an `UPDATE`.  Therefore, no resync of the persister's snapshot state occurs and the event's state does not get altered after the persister executed the delete SQL statement and when the *post*-delete callbacks fire, they're still being provided with the state at the beginning of the entity deletion workflow.

With that said, Envers does record the `REVTYPE=2` (aka `DEL`) in the audit table.  So should you need the timestamp of the removal, you could still obtain it from the Envers `REVINFO` table.

**UPDATE**

Another idea here would be to use two columns rather than a single column.  Instead of using the timestamp as your soft-delete indicator, use a bit-flag

```
@Entity
@Audited
@SQLDelete("UPDATE person SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted is NULL or deleted != true")
public class Person {
  @NotAudited
  private boolean deleted;
  private OffsetDateTime deleteTime;
  @PreRemove
  public void onPreRemove() {
    this.deleteTime = ...;
  }
}
```

Here I use a `@PreRemove` to set the delete time value which should then be passed in the `PostDeleteEvent` to Envers and let Hibernate manage the bit-field.  And since the `deleted` field is never provided in the event state, I marked it as `@NotAudited` to exclude it from the audit schema.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to know the solution from @Naros, we actually got the same problem with this, here is our workaround solution with changing the code on service

```
@Transactional
public void deletePerson(UUID id) {
    PersonEntity personEntity= getPerson(id);
    personEntity.setDeleted(OffsetDateTime.now());
    personRepository.flush();
    personRepository.delete(personEntity);
}
```

There are two main steps we need to focus on:

- Must work on the same transaction (then we marked `@Transactional`)
- And `flush` it.

Not nice, but it works :D, `PostDeleteEvent` will come with `deleted` data

Comment: I see that flush commits any changes made to the entity into the database, so is flush+delete same as save+delete?